# Выбрать записи из таблицы, сгруппировав их по неделям

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток! В таблице есть поле Date в формате timestamp. Как выбрать записи из таблицы, сгруппировав их по неделям? Я пробовал так:

```
GROUP BY(WEEK(`Date`,1))
```

Но это не работает, так как в каждом году недели повторяются от 1 до 54.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный вариант такой

```
GROUP BY(YEARWEEK(`Date`,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

а как вы себе представляете тогда результат группировки по неделям? что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: Еврейский sql отвечает запросом на запрос)))

Comment: @woland
А ви почему спграшиваете?